# tornado set_cookie array support

Tags: cookies, tornado

Does Tornado support array cookie?

In PHP, we set array cookie by

```
setcookie('UserTable[Name]','Tinywan',time()+3600);
setcookie('UserTable[Age]','24',time()+3600);
setcookie('UserTable[Email]','7514@xxx.com',time()+3600);
```

But in tornado, it doesn't work!

```
self.set_cookie('UserTable[Name]', 'Tinywan', expires_days=30)
self.set_cookie('UserTable[Age]', '24', expires_days=30)
self.set_cookie('UserTable[Email]', '7514@xxx.com', expires_days=30)
```

Comment: What you mean by it doesn't work. Are you printing `UserTable` in the same request ? Can you show me your view code ?

Comment: tornado it shows raise CookieError("Illegal key value: %s" % key)

Comment: it's ok when i use self.set_cookie('UserTableName', 'Tinywan', expires_days=30)

Answer (score 0):

It because of the Python Http cookie module raise the error when illegal charater present in the Key

```
from http import cookies


C = cookies.SimpleCookie()
C['UserTable[Name]'] = 'Tinywan'
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/cookies.py", line 521, in __setitem__
    self.__set(key, rval, cval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/cookies.py", line 511, in __set
    M.set(key, real_value, coded_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/cookies.py", line 380, in set
    raise CookieError('Illegal key %r' % (key,))
http.cookies.CookieError: Illegal key 'UserTable[Name]'
>>> C['UserTableName'] = 'Tinywan'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using illegal characters for Cookie name, that is, `[` and `]` characters are illegal.

From [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Directives):

> A `<cookie-name>` can be any US-ASCII characters except control characters (CTLs), spaces, or tabs. It also must not contain a separator character like the following: ( ) < > @ , ; : \ " /  [ ] ? = { }.

You don't really need these characters. `UserTableName` should work fine.